# polar space: number of points and number of i-dimensional singular subspaces

Tags: finite-geometry

I have to look for a formula which gives the number of i-dimensional singular subspaces of a polar space of order $(s,t)$ and rank $n$. My idea was to prove this by induction on $i$. So I wanted to start with calculating the number of points. Here my idea was to use a double counting on the pairs (point, line through that point) but even this did not work. Anyone an idea please how to calculate the number of points in a polar space?

Further I would like to do induction on $i$, but I'm stuck how to calcuate het number of $(i+1)$-dimensional singular subspaces given the number of $i$-dimensional singular subspaces.Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance! I have been searching on it for a very long while so I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you have an idea how to solve this please?

Comment: I don’t – I didn’t know what a polar space is before I looked it up to understand this question.

Comment: I use the Velkamp-Tits axioms of a polar space. Maybe this can help?

Comment: Please, can you give a link to the axioms and/or state them explicitly in your question?